# Simple way to convert Python docstrings from reStructured Text to Google style?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, google-style-guide, sphinx-napoleon

Does anyone now a simple way do convert all docstrings in an existing project from reStructured Text to the [Google format](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Comments)?

It looks like [Napoleon](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) can do something like that, but it looks very complicated, so I figured I'd ask if someone has done that before. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using [pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment/) to convert docstrings from reStructuredText to Google format. Then use Napolean to generate documentation via Sphinx.

> Napoleon is a pre-processor that parses NumPy and Google style docstrings and converts them to reStructuredText before Sphinx attempts to parse them.

Comment: The link you provided gives a 404.

Comment: `Then use Napolean to generate documentation via Sphinx.` is not the part of the question. But thanks for the information since Sphinx couldn't accept google style directly.

Comment: @LukAron the OP said "It looks like Napoleon can do something like that". I elaborated upon when to use Napoleon in my answer, specifically after using pyment.

Answer (score 4):

There is also `docconvert` at https://github.com/cbillingham/docconvert.

I personally found it did a much better job;

- better indentation and line wrapping (personal choice)
- coped with docstrings that were a mix of google and reSTructured styles in the same docstring!